# How to replace a string at the end of a line in a text file with another string in UNIX?

Tags: linux, unix, text-files

I have to replace in a text file the string ".htm" with ".html" if it is placed at the end of line. I should use **sed** but I don't get how to use it. I tried using **grep** instead but didn't work.

Comment: The question is too simple. just search

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
sed 's/\.htm$/.html/' file
```

It looks for `.htm` (the dot has to be escaped) whenever it is followed with end of line (`$`). In that case, it replaces it with `.html`.

If you want to do an in place edit, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\.htm$/.html/' file
```

This will create a backup `file.bak` while the original will be modified with the new data.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello this is.htm
hello this is.htm blabla
hello this ishtm
hi!
$ sed 's/\.htm$/.html/' a
hello this is.html
hello this is.htm blabla
hello this ishtm
hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\.htm$/\.html/' < foo
```

assuming foo is the file that you want to operate.  output will we standard out, redirect it somewhere useful.

Comment: note it is not necessary to use `<`. With `sed ... file` it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

or do the following :

1) Open file in vi editor : vi filename
2) go to command mode :     press :
3) type the following command and press enter: 1,$s/.htm$/.html/

As suggested in other posts, the same results can be achieved using sed command, but in that case you cannnot make changes in the existing file. Instaed you will have to create a new file. Using the solution above, you can make changes in the existing file.

Hope that helps!!